Error on the Function GetAccessTokenForUserAsync during token acquisition
I have implemented Azure AD authentication in our application with code
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Bind(options);
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
}, null, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, null)
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
})
.AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches(options =>
{
    options.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);
}); 

Now I using  var accessToken = await m_tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(Configuration["AzureAd:Scopes:0"].Split(" "),authenticationScheme: CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);  at home controller to received logged in  user token but I I am receiving below error.

authentication scheme was 'Cookies'. Microsoft.Identity.Web inferred
'Cookies' as the authentication scheme. Available authentication
schemes are 'Cookies,OpenIdConnect'. See
https://aka.ms/id-web/authSchemes.  ```


I have searched so many things on the Google but did not find any solutions. same solutions is working on .net 6 but once I have migrated and updated the Nuget Packages from .net 6 to .net 8 it started giving error.
I have changed the Auth Schemes and also tried so many solutions suggested by people but it did not resolved.

Change to
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie

Or to codes below worked for me.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})


Here're the nuget packages I used.
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.4" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.4" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="2.10.0" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.26.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.26.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.26.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.43.0" />
</ItemGroup>


Which .net framework you are using because on .Net 8 it is not working

my test is based on .net 7. I will try it in .net 8

I created a .net 8 MVC application and use codes to test, it worked for me as well.
